# BigInt C++ library consistency with bases

Tags: c++, bigint

Recently I needed a BigInt C++ library and I found [this](https://sites.google.com/site/indy256/algo_cpp/bigint).

But I wasn't able to figure out what does the const int base and base_digits specified at the top mean.

Also what is meant by "base and base_digits must be consistent".

And if I want a base=10, what value of base_digits should I choose?

I tried putting base = 10 and base_digits = 1 but the output changed to something Incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'base' of this implementation is used for the structure's representation of a large integer. If you think of the base in terms of the classic definition of a number base (e.g. base 2 = binary) the implementation stores each 'digit' as an int in a vector. In other words, the implementation is representing your large integer as a vector of one or more 'digits' in base n, where n by default = 1000000000.

"base and base_digits must be consistent" simply because the implementation uses base_digits in some places as a shortcut to working out the length of the value of base in actual decimal (base 10) digits.

You would not want to use base = 10, as then you would be representing each individual digit of your integer as a separate integer inside the vector - not very efficient! If you used base = 100 you would represent each pair of digits with an integer in the vector, base = 1000 would represent each triplet with an integer, and so on.

Comment: Say I want to use base = 10, then the base_digits should be = 1 according to your explanation but it produces incorrect results

Comment: Also, If I change the value of base and base_digits to anything other than the defaults then the output becomes incorrect, why so?

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure about that. Could you give an example? Scanning through the code there looks as though it should work.

Comment: My bad. It actually works. There were some other bugs in the implementation. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I've tried a few different bases and I get the same results using the example built into the code.

Comment: Ah, we just crossed comments! No problem.